# How to manage z-order with a webview playing flash

Tags: android, flash, android-layout, layout, webview

I'm just trying to put a textview, over a Webview, it works fine, but if the webview has a flash object, say a .swf it will go over anything else on the layout hiding my TextView. Tried with RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, ofc declaring the TextView at the end of the layout.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have flash object in the html, you can't put z-index property for any tag html to put the tag over flash object.

But if the flash object has the property wmode = transparent could work.

I hope that helps

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Also pay attantion to hardware acceleration parameter of flash object. It can affect wmode...